# PHP CPU utilization limit

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

I have done some research on the net regarding the problem. My questions is NOT how to reduce cpu utilization by improving algorithm or improving the performance by using multitasking or limiting CPU per system user.

I have a website where user logs in does some processing and logout. The site uses linux server, php and apache. The problem is that I cant control the amount of CPU allocated to each user. ie I want give a guarantee that a user will get say atleast 5% of CPU (assume total number of users is less than 20). How can I do this?

Any solution (A php code, apache server settings, or any out of box soln) is welcomed.

Thankyou very much for reading this :)

Comment: What distro/OS are you using?

Comment: @Mife I am using Ubuntu with bitnami LAMP stack. I can use any distro if that would help

Answer (score 2):

If you use PHP as CGI or FCGI application you could use cpulimit to limit cputime for the PHP process.

Comment: But this will limit the entire PHP utilization. This is not what I need

Comment: You must use separate PHP processes per user to do this.  The OS controls the scheduler, and PHP is an inappropriate language for doing process scheduling.  Therefore breaking each user into a separate process and using `cputime` is a solution where you can continue to use PHP and modify the scheduler's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate how much cpu each of your scripts do then store it a database and for everytime a user calls for your php script it keeps adding to the database with their ID saved for later use.

Here is a quick example

```
$start = microtime(true); 
// Your script here
$end = microtime(true);
```

Then set a cpu limit checker at the start of your php script that querys the database for the current user cpu use. 
If their cpu usage is higher or equal of what they are allowed then display something else instead.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I dont want to limit the application. ie even if the time is greater than a limit, I want it to be completed. The real problem is I want to give fairness to all users not to limit them

Comment: You can't be 'fair to all users' without imposing a limit at some level.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue with your question is that it's already solved.
Apache/PHP is designed to create a separate process for each request, and the OS is splitting the CPU time among them.

**So your setup is already doing what you are trying to achieve.**

e.g. 5 requests doing the same amount of work will get 20% of CPU each, and finish in 5x the time it would require for 1 to run alone. I think that's what you expect.

Some low-level languages may break that equity, but I don't expect PHP to.

**Quick thought, though**:
Being fair isn't efficient. Let say my task takes 1s. Splitting ressources between 5 tasks means all 5 will end at the same time after 5s. Meanwhile, taking turns, the 1st task would have ended after 1s, 2nd after 2s... 5th after 5s. Nobody would lose compare to the "fair" solution. But some would win, which is unfair indeed.